# Print What Binding Guice is Currently Fulfilling

Tags: java, guice

I would like to print why a certain Guice provider is being called (i.e. print the dependency chain for whatever is currently being injected).

For example (trivial example),
I know that Foo has a Bar injected, but BarProvider is being called twice, and I want to know where else Bar is being injected. In BarProvider, I would like to be able to write something like `System.out.println(Guice.getDependencyChain());` and have something like the following printed:

```
at com.mycompany.BarProvider.get(BarProvider.java:23) (via modules: com.mycompany.ServerModule -> com.mycompany.BarModule)
  while locating com.mycompany.MonkeyBars
    for the 2nd parameter of com.mycompany.Playground(Playground.java:190)
```

Comment: It's possible to get a `Provider` object that's not associated with any particular dependency chain, e.g. by using `Injector.getProvider()` or even `Binder.getProvider()` before an `Injector` even exists! What dependency chain do you want in that case? (I think a `ProvisionListener` is what you're looking for, but it's not an exact fit for what you describe.)

Comment: Actually, thinking about this more, I'm less certain of what you want. It's perfectly legitimate for a type to inject `Provider<Bar>` and use it as a factory for `Bar` instances -- there is no requirement that you only inject `Bar` once. (This is a common pattern where you are going to need to create a bunch of threads and each thread needs to have its own instance of a non-thread safe injected object, for example.)

Comment: I want to print the things that depend on Bar. For example, let's say I already knew that MonkeyBars depends on a Bar, and Playground needs a MonkeyBars in order to be constructed. I am only expecting one Playground to be built, but more Bars are getting provided than I expected. How do I find out that Bar is also getting provided to build a AlcoholBar?